# Ionic http get request (with Ionic) returns html data

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using **Ionic** and making `http` request like this:

```
$http.get('//GLOBAL.IP/?username=' + username + '&content_type=json')
            .then(function (result) {
                $scope.days = [];

                alert(JSON.stringify(result));

                for (first in result.data.weeks) break;

                var currentWeek = result.data.weeks[first];
                var time = currentWeek.overall.as_time;

                $scope.week = currentWeek;
                for (day in currentWeek.days.sort().reverse()) {
                    if (day < 2) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    var currentDay = currentWeek.days[day];
                    $scope.days.push(currentDay);

                    if (currentDay.present) {
                        console.log(parseInt(currentDay.work_time_balance) + parseInt(currentWeek.overall.seconds));
                    }

                }
            }, function (result) {

                alert(JSON.stringify(result));

                $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Error',
                    template: 'Connection failed, try again later!'
                });
            })
            .finally(function () {
                // Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
                $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
            });
```

While I am opening app in browser with command `ionic serve`, everything seems working okay, I've already fixed `CORS` and other stuff.
But when In mobile app, I am getting this (sorry for not providing plaintext)

[image]

*UPDATE*

```
        $http.get('//GLOBAL.IP/?username=' + username + '&content_type=json')
            .then(function (result) {
                alert('Good');
            }, function (result) {
                alert('Bad');
            })
```

This code returns me `GOOD`, but `result.data` is still with script tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many `script` tags with `addRow` in ionic http request response, was because of `//` in the beginning of uri, protocol was selecting successfully in browser, but not in compiled app.

Answer (score 1):

When you are testing this app in working mode what is `localhost`, Its a local server running on same machine, right.

When you install or run app in your mobile device where it is pointing to? Do you know that, If code is okay then replacing `localhost` with IP of your machine should resolve this issue.

Comment: Hey, yes,  i ll modify my question, actually ip is "global" and http request tells me what it is successfull, just "data" is very strange.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer isnt fixing the problem, so it's not really an "answer"